# Clipping raster brick object in R

Tags: raster, r, clip

1. I have MODIS NDVI TIFF files for a year
2. I want to first clip it with a irregular polygon (not by its extent only) of my study area and save it as a multi band raster in TIFF format
   The TIFF image are already projected to the needed coordinate system and datum (WGS 84, UTM 45N)
3. I used the `writeRaster()` function for the `rasterbrick` object but it gives me an error.

   If anyone has faced similar problems or could you suggest me better way doing this task.

   > > writeRaster(ndvit1, filename="ndvi_2015t1.tif", bandorder='BSQ', format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
   > >     Error in rgdal::putRasterData(x@file@transient, vv, band = i, offset = off) : 
   > >     Failure during raster IO
   > >     In addition: Warning message:
   > >     closing unused connection 4 (C:\Users\Ghimirebr\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwJschv\raster\r_tmp_2016-04-11_121550_3352_50703.gri)

```r
## Clip a raster (brick) with the polygon (shape file) in its extent
## and mask value nan for the remaining area.

library(raster)
library(rgdal)

# Setting working directory:

setwd("C:/Working_Folder/R")
ndvi_path <- "ndvi_2015"

# Reading the shapefile 
myShapeInR <- readOGR("C:/working_folder/Boundary", 
                      "Chitwan_Nawal_Boundary")

# To view the summary of vector file
summary(myShapeInR)

# Getting the spatial extent of the shapefile 
e <- extent(myShapeInR) 

# Reading the raster you want to crop 
all_ndvi <- list.files(ndvi_path,
                       full.names = TRUE,
                       pattern = ".tif$")
ndvi_stack <- stack(all_ndvi)
ndvi_brick <- brick(ndvi_stack)

# Converting from -1 to 1 (NDVI)
ndvit1 <- ndvi_brick*0.0001

# Saving the RASTER BRICK
writeRaster(ndvit1, filename="ndvi_2015t1.tif", bandorder='BSQ',
            format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
# myraster <- raster(myraster.filename) 

# Cropping the raster to the shapefile spatial extent 
ndvit1.crop <- crop(raster, e, snap="out") 

# Dummy raster with a spatial extension equal to the cropped raster, 
# but full of NA values 
crop <- setValues(ndvit1.crop, NA) 

# Rasterize the catchment boundaries, with NA outside the catchment boundaries 
myShapeInR.r <- rasterize(myShapeInR, crop) 

# Putting NA values in all the raster cells outside the shapefile boundaries 
ndvit1.masked <- mask(x=ndvit1.crop, mask=myShapeInR.r)
```

Comment: You can nest the process using `mask(crop(x, extent(m)), m)` and you do not need the `setValues` step. Sometime ago this was necessary but not any longer. You also do not need to pasteurize your polygon mask.

Answer (score 1):

In order to write a raster stack or brick, the Interleave band can be used in the option argument.

```
    writeRaster(ndvi_stack, filename="<filename>.tif", options="INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite=TRUE)
```